# WPF: Can't get a list of selected files in ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

Here's my problem:

I have a ListBox, to which I add items after I click a button:

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\", "*.csv");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    Settings.AllFilesList.Add(new CsvFile(fileName));
    FilesListListBox.Items.Add(fileName);
}
```

It works as it should.

Now, my ListBox (FilesListListBox) has SelectionMode set to "Multiple".
What I need now is the ability to save the selected files in a list called SelectedFilesList. As you can see above, all files are stored in a list called AllFilesList.

How can I do that?

i tried:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var file in FilesListListBox.SelectedItems)
    {
        Settings.SelectedFilesList.Add(file);
    }
}
```

but it didn't work. I think that in the foreach loop above, every file object is just a string containing a name of the file, so that's why it doesn't work. My SelectedFilesList need objects of type CsvFile.

```
public class CsvFile
{       
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CsvFile(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just adding the file name in the list add the CsvFile. To do that change the way you fill the FilesListListBox to:

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "*.csv");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    var csvFile = new CsvFile(fileName);
    Settings.AllFilesList.Add(csvFile);
    FilesListListBox.Items.Add(csvFile );
}
```

And then just add DisplayMemberPath to the FilesListListBox so it displays the name instead of doing ToString() of the CsvFile.

```
FilesListListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

or you can do it in XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="FilesListListBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

EDIT

And this is how you add the items to your collection latter:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (CsvFile file in FilesListListBox.SelectedItems)
    {
        Settings.SelectedFilesList.Add(file);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to do it in one row and assuming Settings.SelectedFilesList supports AddRange using Linq:

```
Settings.SelectedFilesList.AddRange(FilesListListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<CsvFile>());
```

Comment: Can you add a comment when you down vote as feedback.

Comment: I surely didn't downvote. Thank you for your help, I'm still learning WPF and XAML

Comment: Your solution surely is accurate, but I have no idea how can I put these selected items in my SelectedFilesList. I did all you suggested and then I use 
            foreach (var file in FilesListListBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                Settings.SelectedFilesList.Add(file);
            }

Comment: Added an edit. Basically you need to cast var file, which is of type object, to type CsvFile.

Comment: Where does it show you that at which line in the code?

Comment: No, no, after your edit it's perfect. My comment of invalid argument refered to my code snippet, which didn't work correctly, it lacked casting, as you said. Thanks again for your help